# Screen resolution is not detected correctly when changing the primary display WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 monitors:

**Display 1**

- Real resolution: 1920x1080
- Scale: 125%
- Size considering scale: 1536x864

**Display 2**

- Real resolution: 3840x2560
- Scale: 150%
- Size considering scale: 2560x1636

The **Display 2** is set primary by default. I try to get primary display resolution:

```
// The Display 2 is primary
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceName    // \\.\DISPLAY2
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height // 2560
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width  // 3840
SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight                // 1636
SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth                 // 2560
SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight                    // 1706,66666666667
SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth                     // 2560
```

Screen resolution was detected correctly. Then i changed the primary display to the **Display 1** and i try again get primary display resolution the same way

```
// The Display 1 is primary now
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceName    // \\.\DISPLAY1
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height // 1296
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width  // 2304
SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight                // 793,333333333333
SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth                 // 1536
SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight                    // 864
SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth                     // 1536
```

`System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height` and `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width` are wrong they must be 1920 and 1080.

Those values will be right if i restart the application after changing primary monitor.

How can i get the real resolution of primary display?

Comment: Why mix Forms with WPF? You can do the same that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenwidth?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_SystemParameters_PrimaryScreenWidth does using GetSystemMetrics, shouldn't be terribly difficult.

Comment: I want to get actual size the primary display and as you can see i already tried PrimaryScreenWidth and it shows wrong size

Comment: WinForms was created well before multiple monitors (and high DPI) were the norm.  It doesn't surprise me that there are incompatibilities.